# SQL Job to take backup from server 1 and Restore on server 2

Tags: t-sql, backup, restore

I got a task and i need help , I have to create a job which takes backup from server 1 and after backup is complete another job on server 2 will restore the database. I am using shared network path which is accessible from both servers.

Comment: How you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution might depend on how big the source database is. If it's relatively small, one solution would be:

- Write a stored procedure on `server1` to initiate the database backup (using `COPY_ONLY`), using a fixed database backup name and write the backup file to the share
- Write a stored procedure on `server2` to restore the database (using any appropriate move file commands) using the fixed database backup name (first, dropping the database if it already exists)
- Create a linked server definition on `server2` that points to `server1` with appropriate permission to enable the remote execution of the stored procedure on `server1`
- Create a SQL Server Agent job on `server2` that invokes the backup procedure on `server1` (using the linked server definition) followed by an invocation of the restore stored procedure on `server2`

Comment: The source Database is around 100 GB in size and after backup is it possible to send a acknowledgement to server 2 that database backup is completed and now it is good to restore the database on server 2.

Comment: In my solution, server2 actually initiates the backup on server1 though the execution of the backup procedure on server1 via linked server connection.  Server2 will 'wait' on the completion of the execution of the backup stored procedure on server1 and then you can immediately invoke the restore procedure on server2 - this can all be accomplished in one sql agent job and even in a single job step